# How to use MERGE to update only changed columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-merge, sql-server-2022

I have this query which syncs the target table with the source table. Missing rows in the target need to be inserted, changed rows (only number and name) need to be updated, and missing rows in the source need to be deleted from the target table:

```
MERGE Table1 AS Target
USING Table2 AS Source
    ON Source.id_no = Target.Id
    AND Source.number = Target.Number
    AND Source.[name] = Target.[Name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (Id, Number, [Name]) 
    VALUES (Source.id_no, Source.number, Source.[name])
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    Target.Number = Source.number,
    Target.[Name] = Source.[name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Source THEN
    DELETE
```

But the above is always updating ALL rows every time the query is executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `rowversion` or "last updated time" column? If so that would make it easy. If not, you need to compare **every** column. At least you have access to `IS DISTINCT FROM`.

Comment: No I don't have `rowversion` but I can add it to the target table.

Comment: Also, I would suggest against `MERGE`; especially when you are safeguarding against it basic flaws. See [here](//sqlblog.org/merge).

Comment: You need the column on *both* tables; then you can see if the `rowversion` on the source matches the `binary(8)` on the target.

Comment: Rowversion won't help. You won't be able to synch the target with the source

Comment: Considering it changes when the row changes, @MartinSmith , I don't see why it wouldn't. A last updated time is preferable though.

Comment: The source rows can change any time independent of the target.

Comment: So *both* tables can change independently?

Comment: @ThomA - I meant because any write to the target would update the rowversion to the target - but I see you have since clarified the target would be binary rather than rowversion

Comment: @ThomA Only the source table.

Comment: Then you need something on the source to indicate it has changed,  @IvanDebono .

Comment: @ThomA That would be either the `number` or `name` column or both.

Comment: Then you need to actually compare the values of those columns, @IvanDebono . An Upsert would make this better, imo. Then you can easily implement some `IS DISTINCT FROM` clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
USING Table2 AS Source
    ON Source.id_no = Target.Id
    AND Source.number = Target.Number
    AND Source.[name] = Target.[Name]
```

To just

```
USING Table2 AS Source
    ON Source.id_no = Target.Id
```

Otherwise if, for example, a row exists on both sides and has identical `id` and `name` but different `Number` then you will go through to the `NOT MATCHED BY Target` and `NOT MATCHED BY Source` clauses and never get through to the `UPDATE` branch anyway.

With that change in place you can use

```
WHEN MATCHED AND Target.Number IS DISTINCT FROM Source.number OR
                 Target.[Name] IS DISTINCT FROM  Source.[name] THEN UPDATE ...
```

To compare the "before" and "after" column values and only update if something changed.

```
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS (SELECT Target.Number, Target.[Name] 
                        EXCEPT 
                        SELECT Source.number, Source.[name]) THEN UPDATE ...
```

Is more concise if you have many columns to compare

Comment: @Charlieface true, didn't notice that. Would still be correct result but implement everything as an INSERT or DELETE and make the UPDATE branch redundant.